# SVN to Git migration : Premature end of file

Tags: svn, subgit

I am using Subgit to migrate SVN repos to Git. It is a huge repo (Size of git repo is 86 GB after 75% progress). I am getting following error after 75% progress. I tried `readTimeout = 600000` in subgit config but no success.

Can anyone please suggest me what this error is about and is there any configuration in SVN client/Subgit which I can tweak to fix this issue?

```
[2017-12-02 07:03:53.091][subgit-install][1] svn: E175002: Processing REPORT 
request response failed: Premature end of file. (/svn/pcs/!svn/vcc/default) 
svn: E175002: REPORT request failed on '/svn/pcs/!svn/vcc/default'
com.syntevo.svngitkit.core.a.i: svn: E175002: Processing REPORT request 
response failed: Premature end of file. (/svn/pcs/!svn/vcc/default) 
svn: E175002: REPORT request failed on '/svn/pcs/!svn/vcc/default'
at com.syntevo.svngitkit.core.a.i.a(SourceFile:29)
at com.syntevo.svngitkit.core.b.N.b(SourceFile:655)
at com.syntevo.svngitkit.core.b.N.a(SourceFile:357)
at com.syntevo.svngitkit.core.b.N.a(SourceFile:317)
at com.syntevo.svngitkit.core.b.N.a(SourceFile:263)
at com.syntevo.svngitkit.core.b.N.a(SourceFile:102)
at com.syntevo.svngitkit.core.b.ac.c(SourceFile:43)
at com.syntevo.svngitkit.core.b.ac.b(SourceFile:36)
at org.tmatesoft.translator.k.ap.a(SourceFile:1269)
at org.tmatesoft.translator.k.ap.c(SourceFile:885)
at org.tmatesoft.translator.k.ap.a(SourceFile:908)
at org.tmatesoft.translator.k.ap.b(SourceFile:965)
at org.tmatesoft.translator.k.ap.a(SourceFile:587)
at org.tmatesoft.translator.k.ap.a(SourceFile:558)
at org.tmatesoft.translator.k.d.i.a(SourceFile:203)
at org.tmatesoft.translator.k.d.i.c(SourceFile:90)
at org.tmatesoft.translator.a.Q.b(SourceFile:53)
at org.tmatesoft.translator.a.u.a(SourceFile:23)
at org.tmatesoft.translator.d.a(SourceFile:186)
at org.tmatesoft.translator.d.a(SourceFile:137)
at org.tmatesoft.translator.d.a(SourceFile:51)
at org.tmatesoft.translator.process.f.d(SourceFile:136)
at org.tmatesoft.translator.process.f.c(SourceFile:106)
at org.tmatesoft.translator.d.a(SourceFile:74)
at org.tmatesoft.translator.d.a(SourceFile:65)
at org.tmatesoft.translator.SubGit.main(SourceFile:10)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: Processing REPORT request response failed: Premature end of file. 
(/svn/pcs/!svn/vcc/default)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the description and the stacktrace it look like the SVN repository is being accessed over HTTP(S).
If that's the case, try to enable http spooling by enabling svn.httpSpooling:

[svn]

```
# enable HTTP requests spooling to prevent server-side timeout when request processing takes long time.
httpSpooling = true
```

Another possible acuse for this is incorrect mapping configuration,
but it's hard to tell having stacktrace only what exactly is set improperly, it requires additional analysis.
Try to restart the translation with enabled httpSpooling,
if it fails - please send SubGit's log (subgit-import-*.zip or subgit-install-*.zip)
along with SVN log ('svn log -v' command output) to support@subgit.com for analysis.
With these log it will be possible to find out the cause and resolve the issue.